# How to display all the functions / api available in a class / file in python

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I am very new to python and started using pycharm ide for development.

How to display all the functions / API available in a class/file in python.
e.g. like when we code in scala/java in ide wee get all the functions/ methods available for that class/object by just typing object_name.(dot)   and it shows all the API.
not able to get that for python in pycharm.

for example, I wanted to see all the functions available in the python List. I searched dir(module-name) but that is not what I need while developing faster.

thx in advance.

Comment: do you have suggestion with the following code `[].<caret>`?

Answer (score 0):

`dir(module-name)` and `dir(class-name)` is exactly how you do this. Yes, it doesn't return things in a userfriendly manner and you may need to dig down further for nested modules, but the only better option would be to learn from the package/api docs.